# Multiple declarations errors when overloading typeclass function

Tags: haskell, overloading, typeclass

The following code is a code example for overloading the functions  of the partial ordered typeclass (POrd) from a lecture slide.

When trying to run this code, I get the following multiple declarations errors for the function 'pcompare' and for the operators.

```
> class Eq a => POrd a where
>    pcompare :: a -> a -> Maybe Ordering
>    (~<), (~>), (~<=), (~>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
>
>       -- Minimal complete definition:
>       --      (~<)& (~>) | pcompare
> pcompare x y | x == y       = Just EQ
>              | x ~< y       = Just LT
>              | x ~> y       = Just GT
>              | otherwise    = Nothing
>
> x ~<= y = pcompare x y ==  Just LT || x == y
> x ~<  y = pcompare x y ==  Just LT
> x ~>= y = pcompare x y ==  Just GT || x == y
> x ~>  y = pcompare x y ==  Just GT
```

I get the following error messages:

```
lecture9.lhs:5:1: error:
    Multiple declarations of `pcompare'
    Declared at: lecture9.hs:2:4
                 lecture9.hs:5:1
  |
5 | pcompare x y | x == y       = Just EQ
  | ^^^^^^^^

lecture9.lhs:10:3: error:
    Multiple declarations of `~<='
    Declared at: lecture9.lhs:3:4
                 lecture9.lhs:10:3
   |
10 | x ~<= y = pcompare x y ==  Just LT || x == y
   |   ^^^

lecture9.lhs:11:3: error:
    Multiple declarations of `~<'
    Declared at: lecture9.lhs:3:4
                 lecture9.lhs:11:3
   |
11 | x ~<  y = pcompare x y ==  Just LT
   |   ^^

lecture9.lhs:12:3: error:
    Multiple declarations of `~>='
    Declared at: lecture9.lhs:3:4
                 lecture9.lhs:12:3
   |
12 | x ~>= y = pcompare x y ==  Just GT || x == y
   |   ^^^

lecture9.lhs:13:3: error:
    Multiple declarations of `~>'
    Declared at: lecture9.lhs:3:4
                 lecture9.lhs:13:3
   |
13 | x ~>  y = pcompare x y ==  Just GT
   |   ^^
```

I don't understand  what causes the multiple declarations error in this example, as it looks  very similar to the official PartialOrd typeclass implementation.

Comment: It's hard to be sure because your code has extraneous `>` symbols at the start of each line - but I think this is down to indentation. All this code is part of the typeclass definition so it should all be at the same indentation level, further indented than the `class` declaration itself.

Comment: This is absolutely an indentation problem. Once `pcompare` is declared in the class definition, it can only be "redefined" within an `instance` declaration. By not indenting `pcompare`, you are trying to define it as a regular function.

Comment: @chepner Or within a `class` declaration, as a default implementation! (Which I think is what OP is trying to do.)

Comment: @bradrn I assumed that is what the OP meant as well. I meant to imply that declaration/definition had to occur in the class declaration, but that's not clear from my comment.

Comment: When you have issues with indentation, note that it’s *syntactic sugar* for curly braces around blocks (e.g., `where` & `let`(…`in`), `do`, `case`…`of`) and semicolons between items (resp. declarations & definitions, monadic statements, `case` branches). If you write those explicitly, the issues may become apparent. As the responses have already explained, your indentation meant `class … POrd a where { pcompare :: …; (~<), (~>), (~<=), (~>=) :: …; }; pcompare x y …;  x ~<= y …; …`, that is, the default implementations were *outside* the block but must be *inside* (indented).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters on your question point out, the issue is one of indentation.  For what it's worth, the `>` symbols are appropriate considering you're trying to compile a literate Haskell file (.lhs) rather than a regular Haskell file.  (That said, in a regular Haskell file (.hs), they would cause parsing errors.)

In Haskell, "top-level" declarations are *not* indented at all.  For instance, the definition of the `POrd` class is not indented.  On the flip side, *non*-top-level declarations *must be* indented.  The type declarations of `pcompare` and the other operators are part of the `POrd` class and, as such, are indented.

The definitions of `pcompare` and the other operators must also be indented, but they can technically go in two different places.  They could be defined for particular *instances* of `POrd`, or they could be defined as *defaults* for the `POrd` class.  Based on the definitions themselves, it seems these are intended as defaults.

Long story short, if you indent the definitions of `pcompare` and the other operators, you should be good to go.  (Keep in mind that the `>` still needs to be at the start of the line, so add the extra spaces just after the `>`, as in `>    pcompare x y | x == y ...`.)

Comment: Slight modification to this answer: maybe you should clarify that `>` goes at the beginning _only in a literate Haskell file_.